# How to sum values in multiple rows to a new column in R?

Tags: r, calculated-columns

My dataframe:

```
structure(list(Observation = c("Apple", "Blueberry", "Cirtus", 
"Dates", "Eggplant"), Topic = 1:5, Gamma = c(0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 
0.1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

  Observation Topic Gamma
1       Apple     1   0.1
2   Blueberry     2   0.1
3      Cirtus     3   0.2
4       Dates     4   0.2
5    Eggplant     5   0.1
```

How can I tell R to add the values of 1, 3, and 5, and 2 and 4, and then save it in a new column? For example:

| Observation | Topic | Gamma | new variable |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 1 | .10 | .40 |
| Blueberry | 2 | .10 | .30 |
| Cirtus | 3 | .20 | .40 |
| Dates | 4 | .20 | .30 |
| Eggplant | 5 | .10 | .40 |

Essentially, I'd like each observation to have a new value that sums up the gamma scores of topics 1, 3, and 5, as well as topics 2 and 4.

**Update: Clarification:**
I am not trying to add even topic numbers or odd topic numbers. Sometimes it will be a mixture of both. See this new table as an example:

| Observation | Topic | Gamma | new variable |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 1 | .10 | .10 |
| Blueberry | 2 | .10 | .70 |
| Cirtus | 3 | .20 | .40 |
| Dates | 4 | .20 | .40 |
| Eggplant | 5 | .10 | .70 |
| Fruits | 6 | .50 | .70 |

In this example, I left topic 1 alone, added topics 2, 5, and 6, and added topics 3 and 4.

**Update: Clarification:**

| Observation | Topic | Gamma | new variable |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 1 | .10 | .10 |
| Apple | 2 | .10 | .70 |
| Apple | 3 | .20 | .40 |
| Apple | 4 | .20 | .40 |
| Apple | 5 | .10 | .70 |
| Apple | 6 | .50 | .70 |
| Blueberry | 1 | .20 | .20 |
| Blueberry | 2 | .10 | .60 |
| Blueberry | 3 | .30 | .80 |
| Blueberry | 4 | .50 | .80 |
| Blueberry | 5 | .40 | .60 |
| Blueberry | 6 | .10 | .60 |

In this example, Each fruit (observation) has their own set of values for each topic and I summed the same topics as listed above (2, 5, and 6, 3 and 4) per fruit.

Comment: Thank you so much everyone for your quick reply! I gave these different syntax a try and realized I may have oversimplified the task. Specifically, I am not trying to sum valuables just based on even or odd topics. Sometimes, I will need to add a mixture of both. See edit above for details (posting shortly).

Comment: Please see my update!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update II** on new request:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Observation, grp = case_when(Topic %in% 1 ~ 1,
                           Topic %in% c(2,5,6) ~ 2,
                           Topic %in% c(3,4) ~ 3)) %>% 
  mutate(new_variable = sum(Gamma)) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  select(-grp)
```

```
  Observation Topic Gamma new_variable
   <chr>       <int> <dbl>        <dbl>
 1 Apple           1   0.1          0.1
 2 Apple           2   0.1          0.7
 3 Apple           3   0.2          0.4
 4 Apple           4   0.2          0.4
 5 Apple           5   0.1          0.7
 6 Apple           6   0.5          0.7
 7 Blueberry       1   0.2          0.2
 8 Blueberry       2   0.1          0.6
 9 Blueberry       3   0.3          0.8
10 Blueberry       4   0.5          0.8
11 Blueberry       5   0.4          0.6
12 Blueberry       6   0.1          0.6
```

**Update:** on new request of OP. This solution is inspired fully by PaulS solution (credits to him):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(grp = case_when(Topic %in% 1 ~ 1,
                           Topic %in% c(2,5,6) ~ 2,
                           Topic %in% c(3,4) ~ 3)) %>% 
  mutate(new_variable = sum(Gamma)) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  select(-grp)
```

```
  Observation Topic Gamma new_variable
  <chr>       <int> <dbl>        <dbl>
1 Apple           1   0.1          0.1
2 Blueberry       2   0.1          0.7
3 Cirtus          3   0.2          0.4
4 Dates           4   0.2          0.4
5 Eggplant        5   0.1          0.7
6 Fruits          6   0.5          0.7
```

**First answer:**
We could sum `Gamma` after identifying odd and even rows in an ifelse statement:
In this case `row_number` could be replaced by `Topic`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(new_variable = ifelse(row_number() %% 2 == 1, 
                               sum(Gamma[row_number() %% 2 == 1]), # odd 1,3,5
                               sum(Gamma[row_number() %% 2 == 0])) # even 2,4
         )
```

```
  Observation Topic Gamma new_variable
1       Apple     1   0.1          0.4
2   Blueberry     2   0.1          0.3
3      Cirtus     3   0.2          0.4
4       Dates     4   0.2          0.3
5    Eggplant     5   0.1          0.4
```

data:

```
structure(list(Observation = c("Apple", "Blueberry", "Cirtus", 
"Dates", "Eggplant"), Topic = 1:5, Gamma = c(0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 
0.1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Microbenchmark: AndrewGB's base R is fastest

[image]

Comment: This was incredibly helpful! Thank you so much!! It generally worked well except that it gave every topic the same value regardless of the fruit. That is my mistake; I think I should have described that each fruit has their own unique value for each topic in the data set. I updated my description above with an example. Any advice on how to adjust this script to reflect this structure? Thanks a ton!!!

Comment: Just add `Observation` to `group_by(Observation, grp = case_when(.....` See my update.

Comment: This is PERFECT!!! Thank you so much; this is incredibly helpful!!!

Comment: @md_14 Just updated the base R option as well to be more flexible with your updates.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

```r
dat <- structure(list(Observation = c("Apple", "Blueberry", "Cirtus", 
                                 "Dates", "Eggplant"), 
                 Topic = 1:5, Gamma = c(0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1)), 
            row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
library(tidyverse)
dat %>% 
  mutate(even = as.numeric(Topic %% 2 == 0)) %>% 
  group_by(even) %>% 
  mutate(new_variable = sum(Gamma))
#> # A tibble: 5 × 5
#> # Groups:   even [2]
#>   Observation Topic Gamma  even new_variable
#>   <chr>       <int> <dbl> <dbl>        <dbl>
#> 1 Apple           1   0.1     0          0.4
#> 2 Blueberry       2   0.1     1          0.3
#> 3 Cirtus          3   0.2     0          0.4
#> 4 Dates           4   0.2     1          0.3
#> 5 Eggplant        5   0.1     0          0.4
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Also good! With this `df %>% 
  group_by(even = as.numeric(Topic %% 2 == 0)) %>% 
  mutate(new_variable = sum(Gamma))` . We could omit the `group_by(even)` line!

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(grp = if_else(Topic %in% c(1, 3, 5), 1, 2)) %>% 
  mutate(new_variable = sum(Gamma)) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  select(-grp)

#> # A tibble: 5 × 4
#>   Observation Topic Gamma new_variable
#>   <chr>       <int> <dbl>        <dbl>
#> 1 Apple           1   0.1          0.4
#> 2 Blueberry       2   0.1          0.3
#> 3 Cirtus          3   0.2          0.4
#> 4 Dates           4   0.2          0.3
#> 5 Eggplant        5   0.1          0.4
```

Comment: I like this approach. I think `group_by(grp = if_else(Topic %% 2 == 1, 1, 2))` would make it more general?!

Comment: Not really, as instead of `c(1, 3, 5)` in my code, the OP may use `seq(1,5,2)` (sequence of odd integers), @TarJae. I am not really sure whether the OP means that the groups are to be even and odd integers though. I also like your solution +1!

Answer (score 1):

**Update II** (but will work with the first update as well)

With base R, we can first create a new grouping column, where we copy the `Topic` column as factor, then we can change the levels according to what rows you want to group together to sum. Then, we can get the sum of the `Gamma` column by the `Topic` and row groups. Then, remove the `grp` column.

```
df$grp <- factor(df$Topic)

levels(df$grp) <- list(
  "1" = 1,
  "2" = c(2,5,6),
  "3" = c(3,4)
)

df$new_variable <- ave(df$Gamma, df[,c(1,4)], FUN = sum)

df <- df[,-4]
```

*Output*

```
   Observation Topic Gamma new_variable
1        Apple     1   0.1          0.1
2        Apple     2   0.1          0.7
3        Apple     3   0.2          0.4
4        Apple     4   0.2          0.4
5        Apple     5   0.1          0.7
6        Apple     6   0.5          0.7
7    Blueberry     1   0.2          0.2
8    Blueberry     2   0.1          0.6
9    Blueberry     3   0.3          0.8
10   Blueberry     4   0.5          0.8
11   Blueberry     5   0.4          0.6
12   Blueberry     6   0.1          0.6
```

*Data*

```
df <- structure(list(Observation = c("Apple", "Apple", "Apple", "Apple", 
"Apple", "Apple", "Blueberry", "Blueberry", "Blueberry", "Blueberry", 
"Blueberry", "Blueberry"), Topic = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), Gamma = c(0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.5, 
0.2, 0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.4, 0.1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

**First Answer**

With base R, we can use `ave` to get the sum for each group. Here, I create the group using a logical since we only have 2 groups.

```
df$new_variable <- ave(df$Gamma, row.names(df) %in% c(1, 3, 5), FUN=sum)
```

**Output**

```
  Observation Topic Gamma new_variable
1       Apple     1   0.1          0.4
2   Blueberry     2   0.1          0.3
3      Cirtus     3   0.2          0.4
4       Dates     4   0.2          0.3
5    Eggplant     5   0.1          0.4
```

Or we could get the sum for each grouping of rows and assign to a new column by index.

```
df$new_variable[c(1, 3, 5)] <- sum(df$Gamma[c(1, 3, 5)], na.rm = T)
df$new_variable[c(2, 4)] <- sum(df$Gamma[c(2, 4)], na.rm = T)
```